# SQL Merging two or three tables with COUNT() and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't get my code to work :(

There are multiple questions that are asked by users. I need to display users for a kinda user search and then display how many questions each user has asked.

Table 1 (Users):
id,
username,
password,
avatar,
reg_date,
is_banned (ETC...)

Table 2 (questions):
id,
questioner_id,
question, 
answer 1,
answer 2,
answer 3 (ETC...)

I need to merge the two and then display normal user information like username etc but also count the questioner_id rows and display how many questions that user has asked.

This is what I have so far but it just spits out one result and counts everything:

```
SELECT 
    users.id,
    users.username,
    users.avatar_location,
    users.datetime,
    users.last_action,
    users.last_action_description,
    users.is_banned,
    COUNT(questions.questioner_id)
FROM 
    `users` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `questions` 
ON 
    users.id = questions.questioner_id
ORDER BY
    datetime 
    ASC
```

I am sorry in advance for my utter 'noobiness'. I've looked for an hour or two about how to do this but I haven't been able to fix it.

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

Thanks so much for your help! My final add-on questions is  that I now have one more third table and this time I want to count the questions answered now that I have the questions asked.

Table 3 (questions_answered):
id,
question_id,
user_id,
correct (ETC...)

I've tried adding it into my query but instead of display the count of questions answered it repeats the result of questions asked.

Here's my updated query (Sorry again, I'm just struggling to get my head around this)

```
SELECT 
    users.id,
    users.username,
    users.avatar_location,
    users.datetime,
    users.last_action,
    users.last_action_description,
    users.is_banned,
    COUNT(questions_answered.question_id),
    COUNT(questions.questioner_id)
FROM 
    `users` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `questions` 
ON 
users.id = questions.questioner_id
LEFT JOIN
    `questions_answered`
ON
    users.id = questions_answered.user_id
GROUP BY
    users.id,
    users.username,
    users.avatar_location,
    users.datetime,
    users.last_action,
    users.last_action_description,
    users.is_banned
ORDER BY
    datetime 
    ASC
```

Just thank you so much for your help!

Comment: First, Why `COUNT(questions.questioner_id)`? It cannot be correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first part (Two tables)**

I have my comments in query string:

```
SELECT 
    users.id,
    users.username,
    users.avatar_location,
    users.datetime,
    users.last_action,
    users.last_action_description,
    users.is_banned,
    COUNT(questions.id) as number_of_questions #count each question
FROM 
    `users` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `questions` 
ON 
    users.id = questions.questioner_id
GROUP BY
    users.id # you need to have unique user id in each row
ORDER BY
    questions.datetime # sort by question date right? 
    DESC
```

**For the update (Three tables):**

You need nested selects, you cannot execute count on two columns at the same time. We take the fist select as `users_questions_count` like a table, then every thing is the same as two tables again. The buggy part might come up with ambiguities on names.

```
SELECT 
    users_questions_count.id,
    users_questions_count.username,
    users_questions_count.avatar_location,
    users_questions_count.datetime,
    users_questions_count.last_action,
    users_questions_count.last_action_description,
    users_questions_count.is_banned,
    users_questions_count.number_of_questions,
    COUNT(questions_answered.id) as number_of_answers # make sure you are counting the correct field!
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        users.id as id,
        users.username as username,
        users.avatar_location as avatar_location,
        users.datetime as datetime,
        users.last_action as last_action,
        users.last_action_description as last_action_description,
        users.is_banned as is_banned,
        COUNT(questions.id) as number_of_questions #count each question
    FROM 
        `users` 
    LEFT JOIN 
        `questions` 
    ON 
        users.id = questions.questioner_id
    GROUP BY
        users.id 
    ) as users_questions_count
LEFT JOIN 
    `questions_answered` 
ON 
    users_questions_count.id = questions_answered.user_id
GROUP BY
    users_questions_count.id
```

The general idea for three tables (`table1`, `table2`, `table3` joining on `table1.id`, `table2.item_id`, `table3.item_id`):

```
SELECT 
    table1_table2_count.id,
    table1_table2_count.counter_1,
    COUNT(table3.id) as counter_2
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        table1.id as id,
        COUNT(table2.id) as counter_1
    FROM 
        `table1` 
    LEFT JOIN 
        `table2` 
    ON 
        table1.id = table2.item_id
    GROUP BY
        table1.id 
    ) as table1_table2_count
LEFT JOIN 
    `table3` 
ON 
    table1_table2_count.id = table3.item_id
GROUP BY
    table1_table2_count.id
```

But it would be better to find a solution to avoid these kinds of selections in practically huge data. If you could update one table and put `counter_1`, and `counter_2` on it the writing process will become slower but reading (searching) will be come faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mehdi! Really appreciate it :) Maybe you'd be able to help me with another edit I have in this post? :)

Comment: You are an utter genius! Thanks so much, Mehdi! Really really appreciate all of your help. Just thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add `GROUP BY` to your query:

```
SELECT 
    users.id,
    users.username,
    users.avatar_location,
    users.datetime,
    users.last_action,
    users.last_action_description,
    users.is_banned,
    COUNT(questions.questioner_id)
FROM 
    `users` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `questions` 
ON 
    users.id = questions.questioner_id
GROUP BY
    users.id,
    users.username,
    users.avatar_location,
    users.datetime,
    users.last_action,
    users.last_action_description,
    users.is_banned
ORDER BY
    datetime 
    ASC
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nicolai! It worked! I've added one little bit extra if you have time to help again for a third table.